# Install Winpcap on Windows XP without admin rights

Tags: windows-xp, non-admin, winpcap

Is there a way to install Winpcap on Windows XP without admin rights?

Comment: You could always compile it from source.

Comment: Guess you are trying Firesheep... Your wireless card prob won't capture packets unless run as an admin anyway, so even if you could run pcap, it won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can take advantage of [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to use the portable version of [Winpcap](http://wiki.wireshark.org/WinPcap). You won't need admin rights as they are portable apps.

Comment: And this probably could be used for analyzing logs only, not for capturing data, since putting a NIC into promiscuous mode still requires administrator privileges.